# Wondering how to work with If statements properly and assigning things with list comprehension

Tags: python

So, I'm currently working on this code to learn more about list comp:

```
lowercase = list(letter for letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
uppercase = list(letter for letter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")


print(
    list(
        alphabet[(len(alphabet) - 1) - index2]
        for index, letter in enumerate(str(input("Please input the text: ")))
        for index2, letter2 in enumerate(alphabet)
        if letter.islower() == True  # I want to make alphabet equal to the lowercase list here, with another statement doing the same if it's upper
        if letter == letter2
    )
)
```

The problem I'm finding here is making alphabet equal to the lowercase list if the letter in the first for loop ends up being lowercase - vice versa for uppercase. This isn't by any means a good code, but I'm looking to just learn for now.

Comment: You don't need the comprehensions in the first two lines.  Strings are iterables, just like lists.  And what is `alphabet`?  You haven't defined that.

Comment: `if letter.islower() == True` is better as `if letter.islower()`.  Are you just trying to do a reversing cipher here?

Comment: You don't have any list comprehensions. You are just calling the type directly, with a generator expression as the argument. A list comprehension is a type of list display, like `[letter for letter in "abc..."]`.

Comment: Note the difference between `list("abc...")` and `["abc..."]` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you'd write a reversing cipher.  Note that:

1. You don't need to convert the alphabets to lists
2. You don't need to call `str()` for an `input`; `input` always returns a string
3. You don't need to enumerate the input text, because you never use the enumeration
4. You don't need a loop to search the alphabet, you can use `index`
5. You don't need the `islower` check, because you already check whether the letter is in the alphabet.

```
lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
uppercase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

alphabet = lowercase

print(
    list(
        alphabet[(len(alphabet) - 1) - alphabet.index(letter)]
        for letter in input("Please input the text: ")
        if letter in alphabet
    )
)
```

If you replace `list` with `''.join`, it will print a string instead of a list.

Comment: oh, that's cool, I don't really know much about index so will look into it, thanks a lot.